# Parameter Driven XML Data Source URL

Tags: actuate

i have read this [article](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/files/file/511-parameter-driven-xml-data-source-url/) that how to Driven Xml Data Source URL with Parameters.

but i use BIRD Spreadsheet Designer Actuate 11 SP3, it haven't data source's beforeOpen event.  and i haven't found anyway to bind property on XML data source.

```
http://localhost:8080/RestServer/RptServlet?abc=params["abc"].value
```

please help me to bind abc report parameter to Xml DataSource, so i can use this parameter as above.